# Switching from table to graph give wrong data

Tags: commerce, charts

I'm using the Drupal Commerce Report module as a base for my stats. I have a table which give me data about my sales per month.

[image]

I'd like to use graph instead of table, to make it easier to compare. For some reason, the coma is gone, so all my sales reports are wrong

[image]

I tried to alter data in a pre_render, in a preprocess (by checking the format, test with a dot instead of a coma) but still having the wrong result

Answer (score 0):

This was caused because the value where rewritted in the view (thousand separator, number after coma...). Reverted to initial configuration solved the problem.